# File List Not Displaying on Website Running on Apache2 Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, apache2

I currently upgraded our local server hosting our website from Apache (2.2.22) to Apache (2.4.7). I want to keep the view as-is of the raw file,

[image]

After the upgrade, this page now shows that there is nothing in the folder
[image]
. Nothing was changed in this folder after the upgrade, so I am not sure why it isn't displaying.

I have already tried changing the permissions to 777 for the folder to no avail. Oddly enough, another folder in the same parent directory contains only images (.png) and displays correctly. I have looked into fixing this error by editing the .htaccess file (adding "Options +Index").

Any help would be appreciated, I am having a hard time figuring out what to look up for this issue -- the rest of the website is displaying fine.